# Https nodeJS with JADE not display website correctly

Tags: node.js, https, pug

I have a nodejs site with JADE, after updated to https. The login screen not displaying property. Elements(div), button, text are stretched instead center in middle of screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a mixed content problem: make sure that all resources (js, css, images, ...) are loaded over https.

For security reason browsers block more or less agressivly unsecure ressources loaded from a secure page.

For that, the path of the resources shouldn't start with "http://" (relative path are fine, for example starting with "/" or "//")

Note: that problem can't be solved by a redirect on the server.